# angular to web API with send params to server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I try to send params from angular to web API with function, and it didn't work.
but anther function in the same bracket work.

i try any fingh,
chenge the method to GET from Post and chenge the params to data, send obj or jison and still nothing.

how can I solved this?

Client side:

```
//Don't Work
$http({
    url: "/api/UserApi",
    method: "Post",
    params: {
      userName: $scope.user,
      password: $scope.pass,
      firstName: $scope.FirstName,
      lastName: $scope.LastName,
      identityNumber: $scope.ID,
      email: $scope.mail,
      birthDate: $scope.BDate,
    }
  })
  .success(function(result) {
    alert("Sucsess");
  })
  .error(function(err) {
    alert("faill");
    return;
  });
//Work
$http({
  url: "/api/User",
  method: "Post",
  data: user,
  success: function(data, status) {

    alert("Sucsess");
  }
});



Server Side:
```

Server Side:

```
  //don't arrive here...
  public class UserApiController: ApiController {
    public int AddUser(string userName, string password, string firstName, string lastName, string identityNumber, string email, DateTime birthDate) {
      UserLogic logic = new UserLogic();
      User user = new User();
      user.RoleID = 2;
      user.UserName = userName;
      user.Password = password;
      user.FirstName = firstName;
      user.LastName = lastName;
      user.IdentityNumber = identityNumber;
      user.Email = email;
      user.BirthDate = birthDate;
      return logic.AddUser(user);
    }
  }


//arrive here and work...

public class UserController: ApiController {
  // POST: api/User
  [ResponseType(typeof(User))]
  public IHttpActionResult PostUser(User user) {
    if (!ModelState.IsValid) {
      return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    db.Users.Add(user);
    db.SaveChanges();

    return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new {
      id = user.UserID
    }, user);

  }
}
```

Comment: You should consider editing your post for presentation and clarity of expression.

Comment: If the second method works, why not use it?

Comment: Because I need the too method for different function.